# Is it possible in DevTools to break site JS when one of local variables contains specified value?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I want to figure out decryption algorithm for files of one website. It first loads encrypted files and then with some intricate manipulations with JS it generates the `UInt8Array` of decrypted binary data. The generated data is the same for the same URL. I tried reverse engineering the process but I get absolutely lost in JS function calls when callstack deapth reaches near hundreds.

My question is whether I can somehow track at which line of code the array of decrypted data first appears in local variables. I know what value it will have for one specific URL, so I need a method that would search for that value in local variables at each step of JS execution and break when it finds that value in local variables. Is it possible? Or maybe I can achieve my goal in a different way?

Comment: No, you can only breakpoint when a specific (known beforehand) variable gets a certain value. There is no tool to "search all variables" that I know of.

Comment: Have you considered asking this question the website developers for that website? I suspect I already know the answer. At a minimum you could ask them for the originals. Again, probably don't want to ask. If you tell me the website, I'll ask for you and then direct them to your question here so they can answer for you. LOL